# Creating a new document with an NSDocumentController subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument

I have an NSDocumentController subclass and I'm overriding the -newDocument: method.

How do I create a new document with a title?  This is the short version of what I have which works but the document first shows with "Untitled" and then changes to my custom title.  I would like the new document to open up immediately with the custom title.

```
MyDocument *document = (MyDocument *)[self openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:YES error:&error];
[document setDisplayName:@"My Title"];
```

I tried this but it doesn't work for me.  The document doesn't show up.

```
MyDocument *document = (MyDocument *)[self openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:NO error:&error];
[document setDisplayName:@"My Title"];
[document showWindows];
```

Comment: Did you try `openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:NO`?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that after I posted but then how do I show the document?

Comment: From the documentation of openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay: If displayDocument is YES, it then sends the new document makeWindowControllers and showWindows messages. You can do the same.

Comment: I tried but calling `-showWindows` does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the step where you make the window controllers associated with the document.

`[document showWindows];` only shows the windows already associated with the document.

You need to send the document `-makeWindowControllers`, or make them yourself, as appropriate, and send the document `-addWindowController:` before sending it `-showWindows`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This almost works.  The window will appear now with my custom name but than quickly reverts to an "Untitled" display name after about one second.

Comment: This works correctly for me in a trivial sample application. My advice at this point is to set a breakpoint on `-[NSDocument setDisplayName:]` and `-[NSWindow setTitle:]` to see who is changing the name, and why. You might also wish to consider whether `defaultDraftName` is more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: It's the call to -showWindows that changing the name to "Untitled".

Comment: I reworked my sample app to behave more closely to yours, and I see the problem. It looks like the stored value for displayName is sometimes ignore, and this may be entire in line with the header documentation for the `defaultDraftName` method on NSDocument. It still isn't clear to me why you want a custom name for your untitled documents. Overriding `defaultDraftName` may be the simplest and most correct way to make this happen.